# Comparar dos objetos

Tags: java

Supongamos que tengo

Persona.java

```
String name
String lastname
String address
String city
.. y 20 atributos más
```

Me gustaria comparar dos clases persona pero que me diga solo las diferencias, podría ir atributo por atributo y guardando las diferencia, pero queria saber si hay alguna forma óptima de hacerlo

Por ejemplo si name y city son diferentes, sacar un mensaje:
Name has changed de (antiguo valor) to (nuevo valor)
City has changed de (antiguo valor) to (nuevo valor)

Comment: podrias poner mas informacion? como quieres que "te diga" solo las diferencias? como te diria si algun elemento esta ausente en uno o en otro objeto? piensas reusar esas diferencias despues? cuales son los parametros de desempeño a los que deseas enfocarte? tiempo de ejecucion? uso de memoria? tiempo de compilacion? uso de cpu? uso de hilos?

Comment: modificado mi pregunta

Comment: ¿Óptima en qué sentido?

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas sobre escribir el metodo equals y reimplementarlo segun tus necesidades.

Con esto te quiero decir que debes implementar toda la logica que necesitas.

Por ejemplo

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this.city == o.city
            && this.address == o.address;
}
```

ya implementando lo que necesitas tendriamos algo como esto:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this.city.equals(o.city)) System.out.print("Ciudades diferentes");
    if(this.address.equals(o.address)) System.out.print("Direcciones diferentes");
    return this.city == o.city
            && this.address == o.address;
}
```

Y de esta forma puedes compararlo entre los mismos objetos:

```java
Persona p1 = new Persona("1", "CA", "Dir1");//suspongomas que tiene un constructor de esta forma id, city, address
Persona p2 = new Persona("1", "CA", "Dir2");
p1.equals(p2); //deberia escribir Dorecciones diferentes
```

Espero te sirve saludos

> Perdon por los acentos tengo teclado en ingles.

Comment: Ojo: si cambias equals() es importante cambiar hashCode() también, sino tu objeto puede comportarse de maneras raras en algunos casos

Comment: en el metodo equals, estas añadiendo un equals para cada atributo, queria saber sin necesidad de ir un por uno, imginate que tengo 100 atributos

Comment: Por eso es una sobreescritura del metodo `equals` para que tenga el comportamiento que tu necesites. Y si gracias @AminM se me pasaba eso.

Comment: Con esto me refiero a que si tienes 1000 atributos, pero digamos que segun tu logica para determinar que dos objetos son iguales unicamente necesitas comparar 2 atributos unicamente evaluarias estos.

Comment: si.. importante definir "identidad".. como documento de identidad puede ser una señal que la persona es la misma aunque el nombre o dirección no coincidan perfectamente.

Answer (score -1):

Para recorrer los campos de un objeto, podemos usar lo siguiente:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

void main() {    
   Pers po = new Pers( "Popi", 22 );
   Pers pi = new Pers( "Pipo", 22 );
   recorrerCampos( po, pi );
}

public void recorrerCampos( Object obj, Object obj2 ) {

      // obtenemos la clase de los objetos
   Class<?> clase = obj.getClass();

      // creamos un array con los campos
   Field campos[] = clase.getDeclaredFields();

      // recorremos los campos
   for( Field campo : campos ) {

         // lo hacemos accesible
      campo.setAccessible( true ); // hacemos accesible en campo
      try {

            // obtenemops la clase del campo
         Class<?> claseCampo = campo.getType();

            //  obtenemos los valores de ambos objetos
         Object objetoA = campo.get( obj ); // el valor del campo
         Object objetoB = campo.get( obj2 ); // el valor del campo

            // en base a la clase del campo, comparamos
         if( claseCampo.equals( int.class ) ) {
            if( objetoA != objetoB ) {
               System.out.println( "diferentes" );
            }
         }
         if( claseCampo.equals( String.class ) ) {
            if( !objetoA.equals( objetoB ) ) {
               System.out.println( "diferentes" );
            }
         }
      }
      catch( IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

public class Pers {
   String nombre;
   int edad;
   public Pers( String nom, int años ) {
      nombre = nom;
      edad = años;
   }
}
```